# Seems simple, why won't this work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/TAvtJ/

Trying to do something more complex, but I seem to not understand the basics of adding styles to elements? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Offtopic rant: Can fiddle choose any worse font style/size? Whose bright idea is it to make `=` look like `-`?

Comment: it seems like a normal font to me..

Comment: In FF I find the jsfiddle font difficult to read unless I zoom in more than I need to for most other sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that jsfiddle defaults to putting your code in an `onload` handler, which means your `changeColor()` function was not a global function and wasn't accessible from inline event attributes.

If you look to the left of the jsfiddle page you can choose a framework to include (it defaults to MooTools, but you can use jQuery and various others) and choose whether your JavaScript will be in the head, the body, an onload handler or onDOMReady handler.

So your code works if you include it in the head or body: http://jsfiddle.net/TAvtJ/1/